# Whats the term for websites that automatically resize for mobile?

Tags: mobile

Ive been googling this for a while but can not come back with a term or a way to do it.

Sites such as : http://www.beyond-design.co.uk/ automatically changes design based on the size of the browser(especially for mobile). You can change the browser window width to be really small and see what it is.

What is this technique called?

Thank you :)

Comment: Responsive design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responsive design I believe.

You could look up the techniques used to do this - Javascript / CSS media selectors etc.